# Infinite LOOP - Assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

The program returns an infinite number of r (they should be just 6), so I think the problem is the LOOP istruction, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
section .text

global _start

_start:
    mov ecx, [x] ;x is a constant (5)
_cicloStampa:
    push ecx 
    call _outputsingolocarattere
    pop ecx 
    LOOP _cicloStampa
    jmp _esci
_outputsingolocarattere:
    mov     ecx, stringa
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     0x80
    ret
_esci:
    mov     eax, 1
    mov     ebx, 0
    int     0x80

section .data
    x db 6
    stringa dw  "r"
    len equ $ - stringa
```

Comment: After the loop finishes, it runs into `_outputsingolocarattere`, what happens when it hits the `ret` then, since there is no return address on the stack? I don't really know but my guess is you are missing a jump to `_esci` at the end of the loop.

Comment: I tried adding it, but it still returns infinite 'r'.

Comment: This looks like x86-32 to me, there is no EAX, ECX, etc in x86-16. While I was typing this, @kutschkem posted the comment. Also `x db '6'` looks like ascii '6', that is 0x36. And you seem to move its address to ecx, not the value..

Comment: If I change x db '6' to x db 6 the result is the same :/

Comment: Anyways it moves the the value even if I write x db '6'

Comment: I've edited the code, check it out

Comment: But it still doesn't work

Comment: I'm using a site named jdoodle, anyways I forgot to add NASM in the title. ptr isn't needed in NASM, [x] means the value pointed by x

Comment: Good but what does it load? A byte, a word?

Comment: In this case a double word (dd)

Comment: because of ecx (4B)

Comment: yeah, so you load garbage instead of 6. You need `BYTE [x]` or change `db`.

Comment: Fixed by changing it do dd, thanks a lot ;)