# The code doesn't work, the loop repeats for infinite times

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

My code doesn't work, even if it should, because the value of ecx should be pushed and popped, but it seems like it doesn't make what it should.
I really don't know what the problem could be because I've tried all and I need some support from someone who knows more than me.

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
    call _input
    call _outputsoloecx
    _ciclo:
        push ecx
        call _output
        pop ecx
    LOOP _ciclo
    jmp _exit

_input:
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, input
    mov edx, 1
    int 80h
    ret

_output:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, len
    int 80h
    ret

_outputsoloecx:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov edx, 1
    int 80h
    ret
_exit:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h

section .data
    msg: db "Ciao", 13, 10
    len: equ $ - msg

segment .bss
    input resb 1
    tmp resb 1
```

Comment: Where do you set `ecx` to any sensible value? The last you set seems to be `mov ecx, input` which is an address. It's likely some big-ish value hence you think it's an infinite loop but in reality it's just a lot of iterations and would end sometime :) PS: learn to use a debugger and comment your code especially if you want others to help. We have no idea what you wanted to achieve. PPS: this is not 16 bit code.

Comment: I put mov ecx, [input] but it doesn't work aswell

Comment: It's unclear what you want. If you want to use the input as a count, then you need to convert it from text to number. Make sure you use the appropriate number of bytes. In the simplest case, `movzx ecx, byte [input]; sub ecx, '0'` could work.

Comment: You keep doing the same mistakes as you did here [Infinite LOOP - Assembly 8086](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871038/infinite-loop-assembly-8086) just a few days ago. It is expected that one learns from their mistakes. `I put mov ecx, [input] but it doesn't work aswell` - when seeking for help never describe your problem as 'it doesn't work', this statement does not tell anything to anyone. Also learn to use [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55909627/edit) link under your question to keep all new info in the question body - no one wants to read all the comments..

Comment: Yes, I know, I forgot to reply to Jester, anyways I've just seen it was the same problem. I wrote a test about it, and that's why I didn't have much time to write the question yesterday. To finish I would like to say that I'll try to put more infos about the problem next time.